# Compiling sqlalchemy statements with named parameters

Tags: sqlalchemy

This is a follow up to [Convert sqlalchemy core statements to raw SQL without a connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230688/convert-sqlalchemy-core-statements-to-raw-sql-without-a-connection). I would like to use insert with named arguments, but without executing them through SQLA.

I have an insert statement defined as such:

```
table = Table("table", meta_data,
             Column("id", Integer, auto_increment=True, primary_key=1),
             Column("name", String),
             Column("full_name", String))
params = {"full_name": "some_name", "name": "some_other_name"}
stmt = sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert(table).values(params)
c_stmt = stmt.compile(dialect=dialect)
```

I would later execute this statement through a DBAPI connection. How can I ensure that the position between the generated sql string and my set of parameters is consistent ?

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL engines (all?) support named bind parameters as well as positional parameters, and SA provides an interface (`bindparam`, funny enough) to do so. The [SA Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) have a section with examples that will probably serve your needs. Of course, the examples assume you are executing the queries with SA, so you'll need to interpret them for your use case.

Comment: documentation link is out of date